# NodeJS eclipse V8 deb

Tags: eclipse, debugging, node.js, v8

trying to follow 
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger

eclipse set up, project in workspace, but when I run with the debug configuration:

Failed to connect to Standalone V8 VM
Timed out waiting for handshake

Also, i have multiple .js files. How does Eclipse V8 plugin know which one is the server script for Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use distinct ports per node script. I.E. `5858` for the first script and `5859` for the second.

```
node --debug-brk=5858 MyApp1.js
node --debug-brk=5859 MyApp2.js
```

Comment: i understand how to debug using command line, but don't know about eclipse. what if there is a app.js that contains the main server and another script in the same directory (./script2.js) that is a requirement for app.js? How will eclipse/v8 distinguish?

Comment: It doesnt need to because eclipse does not start the node process for you. The debugger is a stand-alone application that connects to your node process via a specified TCP-Port.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with Eclipse.  I found I actually had another process listening on port 5858.  The following command shows me the processes on port 5858:

```
sudo lsof -i | grep 5858
```